# VRP: How to list all violated constraints for a given assignment?

Tags: or-tools

I have an assignment `routes` for a routing problem. It is a list of lists of stop nodes. `routes[1][5] == 7` is true if node 8 is the 6th stop of the 2nd vehicle (note: *counting from 0*).

`routes` is the solution to a vehicle routing problem without time windows. When I enable the time windows constraint, the routing model informs me that

> ROUTING_FAIL: No solution found to the problem.

Is there a way to set `routes` as the initial solution of the vehicle routing problem with time windows and output all constraints that are violated? I think this would be very helpful when debugging a model. I imagine output like

> *constraint time_dimension.CumulVar(4) <= time_dimension.CumulVar(2) is violated!*